# Executing an anagram checker algorithm in less than a second

Tags: python, python-3.x, anagram

I have created this algorithm to check whether two strings are anagram of each other.
In this exercise, I consider two strings to be anagram of each other if they have the same characters or if they differ just by one. For example math and amth are anagram but even math and maths are anagram.
I need to execute this algorithm in less than a second, but with some examples included in the test it takes sometimes more than 10 minutes. So clearly this can be done way, way better. The nested for loop is the problem but I just can't come up with a possible solution without that.

```
#len(word1) <= len(word2)
def check(word1, word2): 
   lword1 = len(word1)
   lword2 = len(word2)
   sword1 = sorted(word1)
   sword2 = sorted(word2)

   # lword1 == lword2
   if lword1 == lword2: 
       return sword1 == sword2

   # lword1 < lword2, word2 has one more character
   sword2_copy = sword2.copy()
   for c in sword2:
       if c in sword1:
           sword1.remove(c)
           sword2_copy.remove(c)

   return len(sword1) == 0 and len(sword2_copy) == 1


def main(fin, fout, k):

   words = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(fin)] 
   words = [x.strip(' ') for x in words]

   d = {}

   for w1 in words:
       for w2 in words:
           if len(w1) == len(w2) or len(w1) == len(w2) - 1:
               if check(w1, w2):
                   if w1 not in d.keys():
                       d[w1] = [w2]
                   else:
                       d[w1].append(w2)

   highV = list(d.values())[0]
   highK = list(d.keys())[0]
   for key, value in d.items():
       if len(value) > len(highV) or (len(value) == len(highV) and key < highK):
           highK = key
           highV = value

   highV.sort()

   with open(fout, 'w') as f:
       for i in range(len(highV)):
           f.write(highV[i]+' ')
           if (i + 1) % k == 0: 
               f.write('\n')

   return int(len(highV))
```

Comment: Please fix code indentation.

Comment: What input yields in a minutes-long calculation?

Comment: @usr2564301 Text files with more than 10000 strings each long more than 20 characters. I basically need to find the word with the most amount of anagrams in the file.

Comment: are you asking for a high efficiency answer? that may involve migrating this code to C. Python just doesn't have the same memory access that C does.

Comment: @JasonV I'm looking for a way to remove the nested loop which is what is taking long. On a text file with 20000 words it executes the if 400 millions times.

Comment: A simple optimization in addition to using `Counter` is to pre-partition the strings into a list of lists `A` where `A[n]` contains all strings of length `n`. Then, you only need to check for anagram pairs between consecutive lists in `A`.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the Counter from collections:

```
from collections import Counter
str = 'Testanagram'
counter = Counter(str)
print(counter)
> Counter({'a': 3, 'T': 1, 'e': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'n': 1, 'g': 1, 'r': 1, 'm': 1})
```

Using this, you should be much faster - you can also subtract one counter from another to get the diff

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I can't use imports in this test. What I am looking for is a way to remove the nested for loop, which is what takes the most amount of time.

Comment: No need to subtract; just use `Counter(str1) == Counter(str2)`.

Comment: `Counter` doesn't help too much when you need to check for 'off by one'. You can still use Counter to count the characters, but the logic to then decide if only one of the characters is off no more than one for either word slows it down considerably.

Comment: @Grismar I think just subtracting and then checking that at most one element is left should be sufficient for that case.

Comment: I think you need to have two subtractions. See the answer I've posted, it has the (very simple and elegant) `Counter`-based solution, which I think is what you're suggesting. However, that's by far a lot slower than both the OP's suggestion and my own.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work pretty fast, although for my list of words (235,886 of 'em, the full list from `/usr/share/dict/words`) it takes around 2 seconds so it might still be too slow for you. But– honestly, how often do you plan to run it on the entire list?

```
with open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r') as f:
    wordlist = f.readlines()

wordlist = [word.strip() for word in wordlist]
wordlist = [(word,''.join(sorted([kar for kar in word]))) for word in wordlist]

worddict = {}
for word in wordlist:
    if word[1] in worddict:
        worddict[word[1]].append(word[0])
    else:
        worddict[word[1]] = [word[0]]

for word in wordlist:
    if len(worddict[word[1]]) > 1:
        print (worddict[word[1]])
```

Result:

```
['aal', 'ala']
['aam', 'ama']
['aba', 'baa']
['abac', 'caba']
['abactor', 'acrobat']
['abaft', 'bafta']
['abalone', 'balonea']
...
(27,390 lines omitted for brevity)
['ozotype', 'zootype']
['gazy', 'zyga']
['glazy', 'zygal']
[Finished in 2.1s]
```

It creates a dictionary with the sorted characters of each word as the *key* and a list containing just that word itself as its initial *value*. If the key is already present in the dictionary, the word is appended to its list. Then it's only a matter of printing all lists longer than 1 item.

A side effect is that all anagram words appear multiple times. That's logic for you: `incomputable`, which is in this word list, is an anagram of `uncompatible`, and therefore `uncompatible` (per definition *also* in this list) is an anagram of `incomputable`. QED.¹

The largest set of anagram words it finds is this one:

```
['angor', 'argon', 'goran', 'grano', 'groan', 'nagor', 'orang', 'organ', 'rogan']
```

and an interesting pair of opposites is

```
['misrepresentation', 'representationism']
```

The list even contains the word `pythonic':

```
['hypnotic', 'phytonic', 'pythonic', 'typhonic']
```

<sup>¹ After trying: printing each combination only once appeared to be trivial. It reduces the list to 12,189 'unique' sets, and the check took another 0.1 second.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The main optimisation will be in `check()`.

Using something like `collections.Counter`, the solution looks simpler, but is slower:

```
def check_with_counter(word1, word2):
    c1 = Counter(word1)
    c2 = Counter(word2)
    return sum(((c1 - c2) + (c2 - c1)).values()) < 2
```

A solution similar to yours, but considerably faster (by about an order of magnitude)

```
def check_faster(word1, word2):
    # checks faster than check() and works for words of any length (in any order)
    ld = len(word1) - len(word2)
    if ld in [0, 1]:
        sword_long = list(word1)
        sword_short = list(word2)
        if ld == 0:
            return sword_long == sword_short
    elif ld == -1:
        sword_long = list(word2)
        sword_short = list(word1)
    else:
        return False

    for c in sword_short:
        try:
            sword_long.remove(c)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    return len(sword_long) < 2
```

And putting it to use in a somewhat faster `run()`:

```
def run_faster(fin, fout, k):
    words = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(fin)]
    words = [x.strip(' ') for x in words]

    d = {}

    for w1 in words:
        for w2 in words:
            if check_faster(w1, w2):
                if w1 not in d.keys():
                    d[w1] = [w2]
                else:
                    d[w1].append(w2)

    most = 0
    most_anagrams = []
    for word, anagrams in d.items():
        if len(anagrams) > most:
            most = len(anagrams)
            most_anagrams = anagrams

    most_anagrams.sort()

    with open(fout, 'w') as f:
        for i in range(len(most_anagrams)):
            f.write(most_anagrams[i]+' ')
            if (i + 1) % k == 0:
                f.write('\n')

    return int(len(most_anagrams))
```